# Исполнение python скрипты из под планировщика isp

Tags: python, планировщик-задач, isp

Столкнулся со следующим.
К примеру задача скрипта сохранить файл в каталоге

```
f = open('/b_thumbnails.txt','w') # открытие в режиме записи
f.write('WEBVTT' + gg)            # запись....
f.close()                         # закрытие файла
```

Если скрипт запускать в ручную из консоли, файл сохраняет. Но вот если выставить задачу в планировщике isp, скрипт исполнят и без ошибок. Но файл не сохраняет, при чем во всех случаях, что так, что сохранение выхдных файлов из под ffmpeg. При чем все необходимы каталоги создает, а вот файлов в них нет. Нету когда скрипт исполняет систем, опятьже если скрипт запускать из консоли все работает. А из под системы, не сохраняет файлы.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего директория берется от места запуска скрипта.
Попробуйте указать полный путь например 'C:/my_folder/b_thumbnails.txt'.
Можно указать чтобы директория формировалась от расположения скрипта, а не от директории запуска.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from pathlib import PurePath

# Получить директорию где запущен скрипт
dr = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
print(dr)
# Получить путь к скрипту
dr2 = os.path.abspath(__file__)
print(dr2)

# Получаем директорию скрипта
w = PurePath(dr2).parts # разбираем на элементы
scr_dir = ''.join(w[: - 1]) # Убираем имя скрипта
print(scr_dir) # Собираем обратно в строку
```

В вашем случае `open('/b_thumbnails.txt','w')` подразумевает открыть файл для записи если файла нет то создать. Можно поискать в системе где добавился этот файл.

Comment: Путь верный. Если судить о создании катологов. То есть необходимы каталоги по необходимому пути создаются. Проблема в том, что если система запускает скрипт. То в данных каталогах никаких файлов не сохраняет..

Comment: Только создает каталоги и все.

Comment: А путь вовсе такой, просто удалил дабы привести пример 'var/www/gerd/data/www/site.ru/uploads/'

Comment: В чем дело разобрался, но решения пока нет. Есть строчка

Comment: crop = subprocess.check_output("ffmpeg -i "+file+" -ss 10 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print  $NF }' | tail -1", shell=True).decode().strip()

Comment: До нее система сохраняет файл, а вот после нее тен по идеи возвращает она crop=*:*:*:*

Comment: Когда запускает система, результат почему та пустой. Если запускать вручную, результат есть. В чем может быть тут трудность в получении данных. Почему в одном случаи на выходе есть рузельтат, а из под системы его нет, то есть пустая переменная.

Comment: Возможно есть ограничения в правах. Насколько я помню в ISP можно сделать запуск от определенного пользователя. Если использовать учетку с правами админа что нибудь изменится?

Comment: В том то и дело, что запускается скрипт из под root. То есть все права есть и запись какталоги на которых установлен друго пользователь тоже есть. Пробовал, но результат был тот же.